# How to read man pages from a remote machine

Tags: linux, remote, man

Reading `man man` indicate that the `-m` switch or its counterpart the `--systems` long switch may be used to specify a remote host to get man pages from.

The page also mentions the `SYSTEM` environment variable to be used for the same purpose.

Apparently simply specifying a remote IP address as an argument to the switch isn't enough to achieve such a convenience.

I'd like to have more elaboration and real examples that would make one to read FreeBSD man pages on Linux for instance.

Comment: Does your version of `man` really indicate you can use the `-m` option to specify a remote host?  That would normally allow you to specify an _alternate operating system_ whose manual pages are installed _on the same host_ (historically via nfs mount) along with manual pages for your current active operating system.

Comment: it thought about that but it was confusing for me, so i needed clarification; it still remains somewhat confusing - to specify an alternative os as a/for directory to search manpages in, if i understand correctly

Comment: excellent, to note, i had to escape the asterisk `/*` in `zsh`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, I don't really believe that `-m`
can display manpages from a `remote` machine. To display a
`manpage` from a remote machine you need something like:

```
$ ssh freebsd  'man man'
MAN(1)                  FreeBSD General Commands Manual                 MAN(1)

NAME
     man -- display online manual documentation pages
(...)
```

or mount a part of the remote system using `nfs` as already suggested.

The `-m` you're asking about makes `man` look for manpages for other
systems on the local system. For example:

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/man/bsd/man1
$ scp freebsd:/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz /usr/man/bsd/man1
$ man -m bsd man
MAN(1)      BSD General Commands Manual                                                                                                                                                              

NAME
     man — display online manual documentation pages
(...)
$ man man
MAN(1)    Manual pager utils                                                                                                                                                                            

NAME
       man - an interface to the on-line reference manuals
(...)
```

Comment: Having ssh open a TTY would be convenient: `ssh -t ...`, then `man` will start a pager.